# PDE using $\theta$ method in Matlab

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I'm trying to solve this problem numerically in Matlab:

$
\left\{ \begin{array}{rl}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} &=  \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} \ \ \ (\star) \\
P(x,0) &= 1 \\
\frac{\partial P(0,t)}{\partial x} &= kP \\
P(1,t) &= 1
\end{array} \right.
$

I considered a discretization of the space $[0,1]$ in $M$ intervals and time $[0,1]$ in $N$ intervals.

First I built a matrix $P$ to save the initial conditions, then for $P(x,0)=1$, I made: $P(m,0) = 1$, and for $P(1,t)$, I made $P(1,n) = 1$.

I used the $\theta$-method:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} &\approx \frac{P^{n+1}_{m}-P^{n}_{m}}{\Delta t}\\
\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial x^2} & \approx \frac{\theta P^{n+1}_{m+1}+(1-\theta)P^{n}_{m+1} -2(\theta P^{n+1}_{m}+(1-\theta)P^{n}_{m})+(\theta P^{n+1}_{m-1}+(1-\theta)P^{n}_{m-1}) }{(\Delta x)^2}
\end{align*}

to obtain the Scheme:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
 \frac{-\theta}{(\Delta x)^2}P^{n+1}_{m-1}+\left( \frac{1}{\Delta t}+\frac{2\theta}{(\Delta x)^2} \right)P^{n+1}_{m}- \frac{-\theta}{(\Delta x)^2} P^{n+1}_{m+1}   \\
 =\frac{1-\theta}{(\Delta x)^2}P^{n}_{m-1}+\left( \frac{1}{\Delta t}-\frac{2(1-\theta)}{(\Delta x)^2} \right)P^{n}_{m}+ \frac{1-\theta}{(\Delta x)^2}P^{n}_{m+1}  
\end{array}
\end{equation}

This scheme builds a system $Ax=b$, where $A$ (tridiagonal) has size $(M+1)\times (M+1)$ and for the first step with fixed time $n=0$, is posible to obtain  the unknowns $P^1_{m-1}$, $P^1_{m}$, $P^1_{m+1}$, because by the inicial conditions, $P^0_{m-1}$, $P^0_{m}$ and $P^0_{m+1}$ are given.

But, I used approximations of order 2, so for the Neumann condition, I need to use an aproximation of order 2: "mirror imaging technique", i.e:
If $J(P)$ is the flux:
\begin{align*}
J(P)_0  &= kP_0 \\
J(P)_0  &= \frac{J(P)_{-\frac{1}{2}}+J(P)_{\frac{1}{2}}}{2} \\ 
J(P)_{i+\frac{1}{2}}  &=  \frac{P_{i+1}-P_i}{\Delta x} 
\end{align*}
with $i=0$:
\begin{align*}
J(P)_0  &= kP_0 \\
J(P)_{-\frac{1}{2}}  &= 2J(P)_0 +  J(P)_{\frac{1}{2}} \\ 
J(P)_{\frac{1}{2}}  &=   \frac{P_{1}-P_0}{\Delta x} 
\end{align*} 
Substituting in equation $(\star)$: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -\frac{J(P)_{\frac{1}{2}}-J(P)_{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\Delta x} &= 0\\
\frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -\frac{J(P)_{\frac{1}{2}}-(2J(P)_0-J(P)_{\frac{1}{2}})}{\Delta x} &= 0\\
\frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -\frac{\frac{P_1-P_0}{h}-(2kP_0-\frac{P_1-P_0}{\Delta x})}{\Delta x} &= 0\\
\frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -\frac{2kP_0}{h} - 2\frac{(P_1-P_0)}{\Delta x^2} &= 0\\
\frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -\frac{2kP_0}{h} - 2\frac{P_1}{\Delta x^2} + 2\frac{P_0}{\Delta x^2} &= 0 \\
\frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -2\frac{P_1}{\Delta x^2} - \frac{2}{\Delta x}(k+\frac{1}{h})P_0 &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Replacing expressions of $\theta$-method  in the above equation:
$$ \frac{P^{n+1}_0-P^n_0}{\Delta t} -\frac{2}{\Delta x^2}\left( \theta P^{n+1}_1 + (1-\theta)P^n_1 \right) - \frac{2(k+\frac{1}{h})}{\Delta x}\left( \theta P^{n+1}_0 + (1-\theta)P^n_0 \right) = 0 $$
Then, grouping terms:
$$\left( \frac{1}{\Delta t} + \frac{2(k+\frac{1}{\Delta x})\theta}{\Delta x}\right) P^{n+1}_0 - \frac{2\theta }{h^2} P^{n+1}_1 =  \left( \frac{1}{\Delta t} - \frac{2(k+\frac{1}{h})(1-\theta)}{\Delta x} \right) P^n_0 + \frac{2(1-\theta)}{\Delta x^2}  P^n_1 $$

Finally using the above equation, the scheme and the another initial condition, I fill entries of $P$ (except those corresponding to the boundary conditions) with row vectors that are solutions of the problem for a fixed time.

Here my questions:

1. Is the deduction for the Neumann condition well done?
2. How does it affect my program  in matlab the Neumann condition? I have particular problems with that because I first thought that only affected the first equation of the system $ Ax = b $, but in that case, the system would have more unknowns than equations and could not solve the system.

Thanks for your help.